# java.lang.ClassCastException: Help me find whats wrong please

Tags: android, java.lang.class

**OK HERE IS XML CODE**  https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Ue5.png

Sigh I have been trying to fix this for over an hour i have no idea whats going on.. I get the error on the last row of code:  `ph0ne= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testphone);`

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        btn1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonGoTonumber);
        btn2= (Button)  findViewById(R.id.test3button);
        layHome = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layHomeddddddd);
        layAddNumer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.test3LAY);
        ph0ne= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testphone);
    }
}
```

edit: for some reason I can't add the XML code.. Here is stackTrace:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.spiratessgmail.myapplication/com.spiratessgmail.myapplication.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
            at com.spiratessgmail.myapplication.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:33)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Provide the stack trace as well.

Comment: Iam sorry Iam new to this, what is stack trace? And why cant I send the XML code..

Comment: We'll need the stack trace (The red error log that shows up in LogCat), but I'm guessing the type of R.id.testphone is not 'EditText'. Either that or 'ph0ne' has the wrong type. Could you post more code too?

Comment: can you post your xml layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

means that you should change

```
 ph0ne= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.testphone);
```

in

`ph0ne= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testphone)`;

or if your View should be a `EditText`, you have to change the view with id testphone (that is a `LinearLayout`) in a `EditText`

Comment: Well that doesn't work. I get red underscored line if I change it to that and it says it requires EditText but found LinearLayout

Comment: Then the problem is that 'ph0ne' has a type of LinearLayout. Please change it to 'TextView ph0ne;' in the initialization.

Comment: @jojo probabily since your closing tag is </LineaLayout>. If you put a <EditText> your close tag must be </EditText>. Or you can remove the closing tag and use just the first tag adding a slash before the final angle bracket

Comment: @Tyler No that gives me the same problem as I had in start:
android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText

Comment: @jojo Yes we really need that xml. I'm not sure if 'testphone' is supposed to be a LinearLayout or an EditText, but the problem is that 'testphone' and 'ph0ne' are not of the same type. So if you want it to be an EditText, define 'ph0ne' as an Edit text, cast it to (EditText), and in the xml, make sure the element with id 'testphone' is an EditText

Comment: @Joseph82 Well this site wont let me add it, says its not correct code or smth similiar..

Comment: what is the error now? the xml seems to be ok. However I can't see buttonGoTonumber and layHomeddddddd

Comment: @Joseph82 I restarted the program and it seems to work now.. But cant be sure since I've been changing/deleting many different XMLS to see if someone would work in the process. I'll update if I get a problem again.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just make a mistake on refering to your design ids, please check your `EditText` 's id, because as you see on your error log, this id `R.id.testphone` refers to a `LinearLayout`, just check your `edit-text`'s id in your XML

Comment: Nope :(.  <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/testphone" />